# Как сделать градиент на кнопку и задать градиенту вечную анимацию?

Tags: html, css3

**Как сделать градиент на кнопку и задать градиенту  вечную анимацию?**

-Сделать градиент получилось, но заставить его двигаться не выходит...подскажите где я допустил ошибку?

```css
#header-button {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 50px;
  width: 171px;
  background-color: #998675;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #736357;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #998675 50%, #fff);
  -webkit-animation: gradient 3s linear infinite;
  animation: gradient 3s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
}

@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="header-button"> GET STARTED </button>
```

Comment: Добавьте код с `html`

Comment: <button id="header-button">
      GET STARTED
     </button>

Comment: Во-первых, не понятно что ты хочешь сделать... Во-вторых у тя ошибка в названии анимации... Разные название...

Comment: Это уже исправил, но оно все равно не работает...

Comment: Хочу, что бы белый градиент проходил по кнопке, через каждый промежуток времени

Comment: На сколько я помню, градиент не поддается анимации...

Comment: Но как тогда можете посоветовать наложить такой эффект на кнопку?

Answer (score 8):

Я бы реализовал так...

```css
#button-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 171px;
}

#header-button {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 371px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  left: -200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #998675 10%, #fff, #998675);
  animation: gradient 3s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    left: -200px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="button-wrap">
  <button id="header-button"></button>
</div>
```

Вариант два, как я понял, вроде автор этого добивался..

```css
#button-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 171px;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
}

#header-button {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 571px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  left: -400px;
  top: -100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #998675 50%, #fff, #998675 55%);
  animation: gradient 3s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    left: -400px;
    top: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
    top: -10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="button-wrap">
  <button id="header-button">  </button>
  <p>GET STARTED</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы очень помогли!)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста...